# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, escaping, elementtree

I'm parsing an xml file which has "iso-8859-15" encoding.

Words  like 'Zürich', 'Aktienrückk' get converted to "&#228 ;" etc.

I tried these suggestions :

```
p = ElementTree.fromstring(u'<p>found "\u62c9\u67cf \u591a\u516c \u56ed"</p>'.encode('utf8'))
>>> p.text
u'found "\u62c9\u67cf \u591a\u516c \u56ed"'
>>> print p.text
```

but I get errors like `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte`

Even this doesn't help

```
content = unicode(mystring.strip(codecs.BOM_UTF8), 'utf-8')
```

I tried a lot of suggestions on Stack Overflow, but I couldn't figure out my way.

I need to write the parsed content back to a html file with same character sets like 'ü'

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the XML before any python code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
p = ElementTree.fromstring(u'<p>found "\u62c9\u67cf \u591a\u516c \u56ed"</p>'.encode('utf8'))
print p.text.encode('utf8')

found "拉柏 多公 园"
```

For your example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from xml.etree import ElementTree
text = 'Aktienrückk'.decode('utf8')
print text.encode('utf8')

 Aktienrückk
```

Don't forget to put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of the file.